# how to unit test a delete method using JustMock lite

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am just getting started with unit testing and now stuck writing a test method for delete. I am using JustMock. Below I have mentioned my controller action method and test method but the test method is not working. The return value of the method is not retaining it's always returning false. Please guide me on what I'm doing wrong here.

This is the test method.

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void Delete_User()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<UserViewModel,User>();

        IStaticMembershipService membershipRepository = Mock.Create<IStaticMembershipService>();

        var mockUserViewModel = new UserViewModel { Id = 1};

        var mockUser = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel, User>(mockUserViewModel);
        var UserRepository = Mock.Create<IUserRepository>();

        Mock.Arrange(() => UserRepository.DeleteUser(mockUser)).Returns(new OperationStatus { Status = true }).MustBeCalled();

        UserController controller = new UserController(UserRepository, membershipRepository);
        ActionResult result = controller.Delete(mockUserViewModel);

        Mock.Assert(() => UserRepository.DeleteUser(mockUser), Occurs.AtLeastOnce());
    }
```

Any relevant controller info.

```
    private IUserRepository _UserRepository;
    private IStaticMembershipService _membershipService;

    public UserController(IUserRepository UserRepo, IStaticMembershipService membershipService)
    {
        _UserRepository = UserRepo;
        _membershipService = membershipService;
    }
```

The repository is mocked correctly but the "opStatus" property getting returned is always false not the value I have specified to be the result in testmethod.

```
    public ActionResult Delete(UserViewModel usr)
    {
        var selectedUser = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel, User>(usr);

        var opStatus = _UserRepository.DeleteUser(selectedUser);
        if (!opStatus.Status)
            throw new System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I hope i have provided enough information. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The `mockUser ` in the test setup and the `selectedUser` in the method under test are different instances so they do not match when the method under test is exercised.

Comment: Any other way of solving this issue here other than setting ignoring all arguments while calling test method here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

`Mock.Arrange(() => UserRepository.DeleteUser(mockUser)).Returns(new OperationStatus { Status = true }).MustBeCalled();`

to:

`Mock.Arrange(() => UserRepository.DeleteUser(mockUser)).IgnoreArguments().Returns(new OperationStatus { Status = true }).MustBeCalled();`

Alternatively, add equality operators to User so that it realises that mockUser  and selectedUser are the 'same'. Or use lambdas for argument matching (see http://www.telerik.com/blogs/handling-arguments-in-justmock-arrangements).